# Need sql query to assign unique id by comparing two fields in multiple rows of oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below kind of data in Oracle table.
We are comparing each row to see whether they are same or different.
We want to add third new column showing UID if records are same

```
SeqID   RefID
12    CO1000348570
14    16071739
14    9594910
13    CO1000348570
12    16071739
11    9594910
15    888745
```

Desired Output

```
SeqID   RefID        UID
12    CO1000348570   U1
14    16071739       U1
14    9594910        U1
13    CO1000348570   U1
12    16071739       U1
11    9594910        U1
15    888745         U2
```

Can someone please provide me sql query or procedure to get the result?

**EDIT**

I want output something like below (first two columns are inputs)

```
SeqID       RefID           UID

Email_18    CO1017537260    U1 
Email_19    CO1008886658    U2 
Email_19    23654191        U2 
Email_19    293063          U2 
Email_20    CO1010562711    U2 
Email_20    CO1015849928    U2 
Email_21    12780751        U3 
Phone_19    CO1017685850    U1 
Phone_19    CO1017537260    U1 
Phone_20    CO1008886658    U2 
Phone_20    23654191        U2 
Phone_22    CO1010562711    U2 
Phone_22    293063          U2 
Phone_23    21562000        U3
```

Comment: How did first 6 rows got value U1 and last U2? It's not very clear

Comment: Is it because the refID column has duplicates for first 6?

Comment: yes, refID and Seq both hae got duplicates but they are crossed between rows. I mean SeqID 12 has got CO1000348570   and 16071739       .

Comment: then if you lookup 16071739       it has got SeqID 14 as well.   Then further, SeqID 14 has got 9594910        , and at last 9594910        has SeqID 11, so basically first 6 rows represent same data which should get U1 as Unique ID, while last row doesn't have any connection so U2 has to be assigned there and so on.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear to me. Please try to better explain the logic behind your needed result(s). Also, you posted two different needed result in the question and in the comment, which one should we consider?

Comment: Same RefID or Same SeqID need to get incremental UID assigned to them, for example in above table U1 has been assigned to two CO1017537260   (Same RefID) and two Phone_19 (Same SeqID). Likewise you can analyse all other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) over (partition BY seqID) > 1
    OR   COUNT(*) over (partition BY refID) > 1
    THEN 'U1'
    ELSE 'U2'
  END UID
FROM your_table t;
```

It'll assign group U1 if same refID is assigned to more than one seqID or same seqID is assigned to more than one refID.

Comment: I want output something like below (first two columns are inputs)

Comment: SeqID RefID UID
Email_18 CO1017537260 U1
Email_19 CO1008886658 U2
Email_19 23654191 U2
Email_19 293063 U2
Email_20 CO1010562711 U2
Email_20 CO1015849928 U2
Email_21 12780751 U3
Phone_19 CO1017685850 U1
Phone_19 CO1017537260 U1
Phone_20 CO1008886658 U2
Phone_20 23654191 U2
Phone_22 CO1010562711 U2
Phone_22 293063 U2
Phone_23 21562000 U3

Comment: ESeqID | PSeqID | RefID  <br/> -----------------------
ByEmail_10 | ByPhone_12 | 15167016  <br/> -----------------------
ByEmail_10 |  | 34435216  <br/> -----------------------
ByPhone_12 | CO1021221042 |   <br/> -----------------------  <br/>  I want to add fourth column which should show NewID lets say U1 for all above 3 rows as they are having same RefID or same SeqID. Can someone please provide me sql query for this ?